# Open a SVN tag with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I tagged my Eclipse workspace with Tortoise SVN. Now I have to make some changes to the tag so I switched the workspace to the tag folder and I found that the workspace has no project inside and old workspace settings were not be copied.
How can I open my tagged workspace with all its old settings and projects?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this following 
[plugin](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/),
a google product which will store your preferences and apply to workspace automatically